# What does it mean, "for the mosquitoes"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Paul reacted after witnessing living colony for shrunken people not protected against insects and birds:

> Paul: What, and there's no net? No walls?
>
> Jorgen: No, we've been lucky. We are too close to the sea **for the
>   mosquitoes**. And over the years we realized that the birds, they prefer
>   the lemmings.

What does it mean, "for the mosquitoes"?

I find this line from Downsizing 2018 movie.

Comment: All the words in that sentence have their normal meaning.  What is it about that sentence that is hard to understand?

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Do you know what "mosquitoes" are?  Little flies that bite people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are close to the sea, so they don't have to worry about mosquitoes. Mosquitoes don't live near the sea.